# How to validate a field in a elementor form

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Sup guys!

at our company, we have a form to get leads information -> https://www.grupobrandili.com.br/venda-brandili/

Basically, we have build this form using elementor, but, leads information are sent to RD Station using their script.

Our objective with the "CNPJ" field, is that no one can submit the form without filling 18 characters in this field.

actually, we have this php validation code running ->

```
if( strlen( $fields['mascara_cnpj'] )  < 18 || $fields['mascara_cnpj'] === '00.000.000/0000-00') {
    return ['mascara_cnpj', 'CNPJ Inválido' ];
}
```

It actually works at certain point, like, if the user do not fill up the 18 characters, we givehim a error message, but, even with this error message, RD Station still take his data.

idk how to validate this field in a certain way, so rd station stop taking user data even if the user didnt fill up 18 characters

I think there should be a validation at the button, right? if not, how can i make rd station not get the user data if he does not fill up all the 18 characters

Comment: You can validate the user input in the front-end. (Note: if it is a security thing, that is not a good answer)

Comment: Don't use JS. Elementor has built in hooks. Here's a tutorial: https://dev.to/renzoster/validate-form-fields-in-elementor-54cl